# MySQL specialized delete criteria

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete the entire block from a dataset when a minimum requirement (x<15) is met in one of the repititions (see sample data below).

```
+------+-------+------------+----+
| id   | block | repitition | x  |
+------+-------+------------+----+
| 5223 | 1     | 1          | 15 |
| 5223 | 1     | 2          | 17 |
| 5223 | 1     | 3          | 16 |
| 5223 | 2     | 1          | 14 |
| 5223 | 2     | 2          | 15 |
| 6238 | 2     | 1          | 18 |
| 6238 | 2     | 2          | 20 |
| 6238 | 2     | 3          | 12 |  
| 6238 | 2     | 4          | 21 |
| 7575 | 1     | 3          | 13 |
| 7575 | 1     | 4          | 21 |
| 7575 | 1     | 5          | 21 |
+------+-------+------------+----+
```

I was helped in this respect already with the following:

```
delete t1
from your_table t1
inner join
(
    select id, block
    from your_table
    group by id, block
    having sum(x < 15) > 0
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.block = t2.block
```

And this works perfectly.  What I would like to know is if I can do exactly the same, but only if x < 15 is the first repetition in a block - irrespective of the repetition number.

I would therefore like to query the table and let it only delete rows 4, 5, 10, 11, 12.  The current formula will also delete rows 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete t4
from your_table t4
inner join
  (select id,block From YourTable t1
    inner join 
    (  
       select id,block,min(repitition) as FirstRepitition 
       From YourTable Group By id,Block 
    ) t2
    On t1.id = t2.id and t1.block = t2.block 
    and t1.Repitition = t2.FirstRepition and t1.x < 15
  ) t3 
  On t4.id = t3.id and t4.block = t3.block
```

would be one way. Find the earliest repetitions, get the ones where x < 15, then delete the lot. Messy though...

Comment: Thank you so much Tony Hopkinson!  This is perfect!